# Not returning all data

Tags: vb.net, winforms, entity-framework

A little background, I am a web developer who is working on his first `Winform`.

I am using `EF5`. The tables are relational, however the tables only have a primary key. I have a `Winform` with a `GridView` attached to it. This `GridView` is being populated by a `BindingSource`. The `Datasource` for the `BindingSource` is being filled by a Linq query.

---

```
Public Class Form1
    Private batchEnt As BatchMananger.PrintManagerEntities
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try

            batchEnt = New BatchMananger.PrintManagerEntities

            batchBindingSource.DataSource = (From b In batchEnt.AutomatedBatches Join bd In batchEnt.AutomatedBatchResults On b.ID Equals bd.AutomatedBatchID Where b.BatchName <> "" Select b.ID, b.BatchName, b.Description, b.ScheduleDesc, b.BatchResultEmail, b.BatchSourceEmail, bd.ExecutionDateTime, bd.TotalSuccesful, bd.TotalItems, bd.TotalFail).ToList
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

My problem is that the `Gridview` is being populated with only data from the `AutomatedBatches` table and not from the joined table `AutomatedBatchResults`. However, when inspecting the `Datasource` element I see that the joined results are coming back. How would I bind to the `BIndingsource` so that all results from the `Linq` query populate my `Gridview`.

Please let me know if you need more info.

### **UPDATE**

Found out what was wrong. I was not setting the DataPropertyName on the GridView's property. After setting the DataPropertyName to the same name of the database field it worked. I also created an association between the AutomatedBatch (1) to the AutomatedBatchResult (many) in the EF Data Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was wrong. I was not setting the DataPropertyName on the GridView's property. After setting the DataPropertyName to the same name of the database field it worked. I also created an association between the AutomatedBatch (1) to the AutomatedBatchResult (many) in the EF Data Model.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data, at a guess, its your join request which is causing some records from your joined table not to display. Remember the join keyword in linq is an inner join, so any records that do not meet the join condition will not be displayed. To display all records from the tables I'd do the following:

Quick Note -- -Please- add types on all the objects.

```
Private batchEnt As BatchMananger.PrintManagerEntities
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Try
            Dim batchEnt As PrintManagerEntities = New PrintManagerEntities
            Dim batchBindingSource

            Dim batcheswithResults = (From b In batchEnt.AutomatedBatches
                                             Join bd In batchEnt.AutomatedBatchResults  On b.ID Equals bd.AutomatedBatchID
                                             Where b.BatchName <> ""
                                             Select New Results(b, bd)).ToList

            Dim batchesWithoutResults = (From b In batchEnt.AutomatedBatches
                                         Where Not batchEnt.AutomatedBatchResults.Any(Function(o) o.Id = b.Id)
                                         Select New Results(b, Nothing)).ToList

            Dim itemsSource As New List(Of Object)
            itemsSource.AddRange(batcheswithResults)
            itemsSource.AddRange(batchesWithoutResults)

            batchBindingSource.DataSource = itemsSource

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Sub

End Module

Public Class Results
    'TODO: Add types to params and all properties
    Public Sub New(AutomaticBatches, AutomatedBatchResults)
        _automaticBatches = AutomaticBatches
        _automatedBatchResults = AutomatedBatchResults
    End Sub

    Private _automaticBatches
    Private _automatedBatchResults

    Public Property ID
        Get
            Return _automaticBatches.ID
        End Get
        Set(value)
            _automaticBatches.ID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property BatchName
        Get
            Return _automaticBatches.BatchName
        End Get
        Set(value)
            _automaticBatches.BatchName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Description
        Get
            Return _automaticBatches.Description
        End Get
        Set(value)
            _automaticBatches.Description = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property ScheduleDesc
        Get
            Return _automaticBatches.ScheduleDesc
        End Get
        Set(value)
            _automaticBatches.ScheduleDesc = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property BatchResultEmail
        Get
            Return _automaticBatches.BatchResultEmail
        End Get
        Set(value)
            _automaticBatches.BatchResultEmail = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property BatchSourceEmail
        Get
            Return _automaticBatches.BatchSourceEmail
        End Get
        Set(value)
            _automaticBatches.BatchSourceEmail = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property ExecutionDateTime
        Get
            If _automatedBatchResults IsNot Nothing Then Return _automatedBatchResults.ExecutionDateTime
            Return Nothing
        End Get
        Set(value)
            If _automatedBatchResults IsNot Nothing Then _automatedBatchResults.ExecutionDateTime = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property TotalSuccesful
        Get
            If _automatedBatchResults IsNot Nothing Then Return _automatedBatchResults.TotalSuccesful
            Return Nothing
        End Get
        Set(value)
            If _automatedBatchResults IsNot Nothing Then _automatedBatchResults.TotalSuccesful = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property TotalItems
        Get
            If _automatedBatchResults IsNot Nothing Then Return _automatedBatchResults.TotalItems
            Return Nothing
        End Get
        Set(value)
            If _automatedBatchResults IsNot Nothing Then _automatedBatchResults.TotalItems = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property TotalFail
        Get
            If _automatedBatchResults IsNot Nothing Then Return _automatedBatchResults.TotalFail
            Return Nothing
        End Get
        Set(value)
            If _automatedBatchResults IsNot Nothing Then _automatedBatchResults.TotalFail = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: That was my first thought also, but that is not it. When joining the BatchResult.ID to AutomatedBatchResult.AutomatedBatchID the query brings back all data in SQL studio. Also when inspecting the batchBindingSource.DataSource element during debugging it shows all data coming back. However, after the bind only the AutomatedBatch fields are being populated on the grid.